# Multiple loops with asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Is it possible to have multiple loops with asyncio? If the response is yes how can I do that? 
My use case is:
  * I extract urls from a list of websites in async
  * For each "sub url list", I would crawl them in async/

Example to extract urls:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from suburls import extractsuburls

@asyncio.coroutine
def extracturls(url):
    subtasks = []
    response = yield from aiohttp.request('GET', url)
    suburl_list = yield from response.text()
    for suburl in suburl_list:
        subtasks.append(asyncio.Task(extractsuburls(suburl)))
     loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
     loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*subtasks))

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     urls_list = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com']
     for url in url_list: 
          subtasks.append(asyncio.Task(extractsuburls(url)))  
     loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
     loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*subtasks))
     loop.close()
```

If I execute this code I'll have an error when python will try to launch the second loop witch says that a loop is already running.

P.S: my module "extractsuburls" uses aiohttp to perform web request.

EDIT:

Well, I've try this solution:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from suburls import extractsuburls

@asyncio.coroutine
def extracturls( url ):
    subtasks = []
    response = yield from aiohttp.request('GET', url)
    suburl_list = yield from response.text()
    jobs_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    for suburl in suburl_list:
        subtasks.append(asyncio.Task(extractsuburls(suburl)))
     asyncio.new_event_loop(jobs_loop)
     jobs_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*subtasks))
     jobs_loop.close()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     urls_list = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com']
     for url in url_list: 
          subtasks.append(asyncio.Task(extractsuburls(url)))  
     loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
     loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*subtasks))
     loop.close()
```

But I've this error: loop argument must agree with Future

Any idea?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You don't need several event loops, just use `yield from gather(*subtasks)` in `extracturls()` coroutine:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from suburls import extractsuburls

@asyncio.coroutine
def extracturls(url):
    subtasks = []
    response = yield from aiohttp.request('GET', url)
    suburl_list = yield from response.text()
    for suburl in suburl_list:
        subtasks.append(extractsuburls(suburl))
    yield from asyncio.gather(*subtasks)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     urls_list = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com']
     for url in url_list: 
          subtasks.append(extractsuburls(url))
     loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
     loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*subtasks))
     loop.close()
```

As result you get waiting for subtasks until `extracturls` finished.

Comment: Wow! Just perfect. It's exactly what I want. Thanks a lot Andrew.

Comment: Just another question Andrew, with this code, how can I set a timeout for each Task? I want to kill or raise an exception if a Task spend more than 10s. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure! Just wrap task coroutine into `wait_for` call like `asyncio.Task(asyncio.wait_for(extractsuburls(url), 10.0))`

Comment: Nice! Thanks very much Andrew :)

Comment: `asyncio.gather` accepts both coroutines and tasks, so you could skip the two explicit `asyncio.Task` calls.

Comment: @TomPohl sorry for too late reaction but you are right.
I've updated the code sample by removing extra task creations.

Comment: This works. But I really want to know if I can use 2 loops at the same time

Comment: Are you asking about two `loop.run_forever()` calls at the same time in the same thread? It's impossible.